# Issue with mapping the fields when there is an apex webservice xml response (Revised with new errors)

Tags: apex, integration, callout, null-pointer

Apex call out has an xml response.How can I map the fields in Salesforce to the response I receieved. I could map the fields like clean etc. But how could I map fields like make,model, year relatively.

Assume the fields are : Make__c ,Model__c etc.... Considering the XML response.

XML response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <result>
      <vin>xxxxxxxxxxx</vin>
      <id>xxxxxxxxxxx</id>
      <date>2018-02-08 05:02:15 PST</date>
      <specs>
        <VIN />
        *<Year>2011</Year>
        <Make>Chevrolet</Make>
        <Model>Suburban</Model>*
        <Trim>LS 1500</Trim>
        </specs>
      <clean>0</clean>
      <success>1</success>
      <error />
    </result>
```

---

```
public PageReference doVinExtract()
    { 

            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
            httpRequest.setEndpoint('https:/VinProviderxxxx.php');
            String body = 'id=01123999999198&key=xxxxxxx&vin=1GNSKHE34BRxxxxxxx&mode=test&user=vxxxxxx&pass=slll4250&format=xml';
            httpRequest.setBody(body);
            httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
            Http htt = new hTTP();
            HttpResponse httpRe = htt.send(httpRequest);
            system.debug(httpRe.geTbody());
            String re = httpRe.geTbody();

           Dom.Document doc = httpRe.getBodyDocument();
            Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();
            Dom.XMLNode specs = address.getChildElement('specs', null);


          //String clean= address.getChildElement('clean', null).getText();       
          String vinDate= address.getChildElement('date', null).getText();


         String Year = specs.getChildElement('Year', null).getText();
         String Make = specs.getChildElement('Make', null).getText();
        String Model = specs.getChildElement('Model', null).getText();
        String FuelType = specs.getChildElement('FuelType', null).getText();


        // print out specific elements
       for(Dom.XMLNode child : address.getChildElements()) {

             if(child.getName() == 'specs' ){

                           System.debug('******'+child.getText());

           } 


                       System.debug('address: ' + address);
                       System.debug('specs : ' + specs ); 




                           system.debug('result'+ re); 



      }







          Vehicle__c  ve =[select Name, Id,  Year__c, VinDate__c, Fuel_Type__c  from Vehicle__c where id =: vehicleId];



        //ve.Title_Status__c=clean;
         ve.VinDate__c=vinDate;
         ve.Make__c=  Make;
         ve.Model__c= Model;
         ve.Year__c=Year; 
         ve.Fuel_Type__c =FuelType;
          update ve;




           PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('xxxxxxxxx'+ vehicleId);
        return nextPage;   


    }

}
```

The error is :

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!doDirectPayment}' in component  in page vinauditpage: Class.VinAuditCntlr.doDirectPayment: line 44, column 1
>   Class.cxxxCntlr.doVinExtract: line 44, column 1

Sometimes:It shows line 47 Column 1

Is this because of the response might not contain the fields required from salesforce?

I would also like to paste the debug log to have a comprehensive understanding.

```
10:02:34.0 (9170761)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[28]|httpRequest|System.HttpRequest|true|false 10:02:34.0 (9259169)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[28]|httpRequest|"System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=null, Method=null]"|0x3366c69d 10:02:34.0 (9269999)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[29] 10:02:34.0 (9274562)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[29]|Bytes:43 10:02:34.0 (9345602)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[30] 10:02:34.0 (9350259)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[30]|Bytes:37 10:02:34.0 (9468188)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this|{"vehicle":"0x73268d7c","vehicleId":"a1Z350000001SO0EAM","vinNumber":"1FTCF15N5HLA06223"}|0x354564a4 10:02:34.0 (9491272)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[30]|Bytes:66 10:02:34.0 (9506206)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[30]|Bytes:120 10:02:34.0 (9513814)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[30]|body|String|false|false 10:02:34.0 (9527933)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[30]|body|"id=0112399992&key=KY (100 more) ..." 10:02:34.0 (9533681)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[31] 10:02:34.0 (9571678)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[32] 10:02:34.0 (9576000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[32]|Bytes:3 10:02:34.0 (9608165)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[33] 10:02:34.0 (9625502)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[33]|htt|System.Http|true|false 10:02:34.0 (9703491)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[33]|htt|"System.Http[]"|0x2753a4d2 10:02:34.0 (9714121)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[34] 10:02:34.0 (9841060)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[34]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://api-ssl.vinaudit.com/pullreport.php, Method=GET] 10:02:34.0 (269995528)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:548 10:02:34.0 (270179937)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[34]|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200] 10:02:34.0 (270215805)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[34]|Bytes:137 10:02:34.0 (270257158)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[34]|httpRe|System.HttpResponse|true|false 10:02:34.0 (270358223)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[34]|httpRe|"System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]"|0x282fcad7 10:02:34.0 (270371795)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[35] 10:02:34.0 (270381135)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[35]|Bytes:14 10:02:34.0 (270481694)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[35]|Bytes:131 10:02:34.0 (270510107)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[35]|Bytes:145 10:02:34.0 (270538879)|USER_DEBUG|[35]|DEBUG|++++++response 1FTCF15N5HLA062230vin_mismatch 10:02:34.0 (270551659)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[36] 10:02:34.0 (270581910)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[36]|Bytes:131 10:02:34.0 (270596218)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[36]|re|String|false|false 10:02:34.0 (270615631)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[36]|re|"\u003C?xml version=\"1.0\" (111 more) ..." 10:02:34.0 (270622063)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[38] 10:02:34.0 (270721993)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[38]|doc|dom.Document|true|false 10:02:34.0 (270793869)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[38]|doc|"Document[]"|0x27167566 10:02:34.0 (270804484)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[39] 10:02:34.0 (270846500)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[39]|address|dom.XmlNode|true|false 10:02:34.0 (270927026)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[39]|address|"XMLNode[ELEMENT,result,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,vin,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,1FTCF15N5HLA06223,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,success,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,0,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,error,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,vin_mismatch,]],null,]],null,]"|0x644ac164 10:02:34.0 (270942061)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[40] 10:02:34.0 (270947475)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:5 10:02:34.0 (271005113)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[40]|specs|dom.XmlNode|true|false 10:02:34.0 (271020975)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[40]|specs|null| 10:02:34.0 (271026661)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[44] 10:02:34.0 (271031109)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[44]|Bytes:4 10:02:34.0 (271152871)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[44]|Bytes:41 10:02:34.0 (271261662)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.xxx.doVinExtract: line 44, column 1
```

How to avoid these errors and proceed dynamically with the code that returns "null" and points out the response about the field that is not  with Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking whether the child elements you're trying to pull out are `null` prior to calling `getText()`. Check for nullity first, on every single child element you obtain with `getChildElement()`.

Additionally, your `for` loop over child elements is doing nothing at all and can be removed.